# filling rows and column in php with symbols

Tags: php

I want to fill each 10 lines and columns with star. For each line , and for each column "*" and create a block. I don't know how to do it..i'm beginer. I try this code but i don't know is corect.

```
$col =array(1,2,3);
   for($i = 0; $i<10;$i++){
        echo "*<br/>";
   foreach ($col as $key => $value) {
   foreach ($col as $key => $value) {
        echo "*";
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i = 0; $i<10;$i++){
    for($j = 0; $j<10;$j++){
        echo "*";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

If you want this, you can use this algorithm.

xxxxxxxxxx

.
.
.
10 line...

Comment: Thanks man! which would be the  logical to understand better?

Comment: Inner loop prints 10 characters. Then, a new line is printed out from the loop. This is repeated 10 times through the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Print 10 lines containing 10 stars:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    printf("<p>%s</p>",str_repeat("*",10));
}
```

If you don't want it to be printed as paragraphs, you can use `br` like this:

```
printf("%s<br/>",str_repeat("*",10));
```